# Can you break your fall by flying?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, flight, falling

If a character in Pathfinder falls could they break their fall by flying, or would they fall to their potential death?

Comment: If that fails, try attacking the ground and missing.

Answer (score 10):

From the [Fly](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly/) skill:

> If you are falling and have the ability to fly, you can make a DC 10 Fly check to negate the damage. You cannot make this check if you are falling due to a failed Fly check or a collision. See Falling Damage if you fail this check.

Comment: So the flight-capable creature still hits the ground if it's, like, walking along and falls into a pit, yet success on the Fly skill check means that the creature manages to slow its descent to such a degree that the landing's painless?

Comment: Given that you fall down 500 feet in the first round, you probably only have a second or two to react. Enough to cushion the fall, but not enough to actually start flying if you were walking before. More of a special save than an action.

Comment: Based on the phrasing "negate the damage" not "fly instead" (or something better but equally different), you do still land and you're on your feet because no damage was taken. A GM can and frequently probably should rule differently if that interpretation doesn't make sense (IE your winged Aasimar fell into an endless pit... you could probably 'catch' yourself before falling 500ft.)